# Check type without changing it?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I'm getting an unexpected (to me) error after checking the type of a variable. Below is a minimal example, but the full code has classes like ChildB, ChildC, etc., as well as multiple instances of ChildA typed with different enums; the loop has to handle the list's items generically.

The 3rd test below is my workaround, and I was hoping someone could explain why that workaround is necessary; why is the fourth test failing?

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  var settings = [];
  Runner runner = Runner();
  settings.add(ChildA<A>(runner.setA));

  test("passes, no type check, missing specific type handling", () {
    for (var s in settings) {
      runner.go(s.setter);
    }
  });

  test("passes, too-specific type check; info not known in this loop", () {
    for (var s in settings) {
      if (s is ChildA<A>) {
        runner.go(s.setter);
      }
    }
  });

  test("passes, wanted type check on different reference", () {
    for (var s in settings) {
      var t = s;
      if (t is ChildA) {
        runner.go(s.setter);
      }
    }
  });

  // fails with "type '(A) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Enum) => dynamic'"
  test("fails, wanted type check on original reference", () {
    for (var s in settings) {
      if (s is ChildA) {
        runner.go(s.setter);
      }
    }
  });
}

class Parent {}

class ChildA<T extends Enum> extends Parent {
  Function(T) setter;
  ChildA(this.setter);
}

class Runner {
  void go(Function setter) {
    return;
  }

  void setA(A value) {
    return;
  }
}

enum A { a }
```

Comment: just calling "is" should not impact the object in any way.  This isn't like quantum mechanics where the act of observing something causes it to collapse. :)  Something else is going on that you're not describing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add the stack-trace? The reported error doesn't look like raised by the provided code. Mainly the `buildEnumButtons` function.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz That's what I would expect, but toggling that one variable from t to s toggles on this error when passing s.setter. Here's the signature I'm calling ```Widget buildEnumButtons(List<_EnumButtonData> buttons, Function setter)```.

Comment: How is `settings` declared?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz `is` type-promotes local variables.  It does not modify the object, but it *does* change the static type perceived by the compiler.

Comment: @CraigSabbey I presume that you're receiving a compile-time error and not a runtime error?  Which line does the error refer to?  It's hard to answer your question because there is a lot of code that you've haven't provided.  Minimal code that can reproduce the problem would help.

Comment: @lepsch ```settings``` is declared as an empty list, but here's the item that's giving me trouble: ```settings.add(_EnumButtonsSetting<StartupView>("First page", controller.setStartupView, startupViewDisplayData));```

Comment: Is it possible to strip the code down as a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and copy-paste it in the question itself? Just click [edit] and paste it. Without a bit more code it's going to be just guessing.

Comment: My guess is that `s` is of type `dynamic` and that an `s is _EnumButtonsSetting` check doesn't work because it promotes `s` to `_EnumButtonsSettings<dynamic>` where the `dynamic` type parameter is incompatible somewhere later. Promoting `t` instead of `s` avoids a static type error because leaving `s` as `dynamic` disables static type-checking.  If that's what's happening, the proper fix probably is *not* to disable type-promotion, it's to fix the type-check so that it's promoted to the correct type.

Comment: @jamesdlin I am trying to handle these instances generically, I don't know enough about them when I'm looping to specify the type there (I think that's what you're saying). I worked up an example, I'll post that; hopefully that will make it completely clear.